# Accessing object created inside of a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, return

I'm still learning so I might be wording this wronf (which might be why I haven't had any luck in finding an answer by searching thus far) or I might be doing this wrong all together.

Basically I'm trying to create a function that, when called, will create an object (which is made up of other objects). If I create this `Characters` object outside of the function, I can access it as I'd expect to but when done inside the function, I can't seem to access it. I'm testing this in the console built into Chrome.

Here's my code.

```
function q1(ans) {      //Are you male or female?   
    "use strict";
    //store all above objects into new object
    if (ans === "male") {
        var Characters = {
            spike: spike,
            jet: jet,
            vicious: vicious
        };
    }
    if (ans === "female") {
    //store all above objects into new object
        var Characters = {
            faye: faye,
            julia: julia,
            ed: ed
        };
    }
    return Characters;
}
```

*(The objects `spike`, `jet`, `vicious` (etc) are defined elsewhere and can be accessed without any issue.)*

If I call my function `q1("male");` the console seems to log that the `Characters` object is created but if I then try to access it by just typing `Characters` I get an error (ReferenceError: Characters is not defined). If I were to create this Characters object outside of a function and then try to access it as mentioned above, this works fine. This leads me to believe I'm not returning it properly (or I'm doing something else wrong entirely). What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: If you do like this `var Chars = q1("male")` the return value will be meaningful

Comment: That did it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is due to scope. this means that character is only live inside the function so you can't access it outside of the function. what you have to do is set a new variable equal to the return value of the function when u call it. That way you can reference the returned variable outside the function and use it later on.

```
 var male = q1("male")
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already defined characters outside the scope of `q1` you will need to reassign the `Characters` variable by returning Characters from the method.

So reassign the Characters and it should fix the problem.
One more very bad way is to not use `var Characters`, instead use `Characters = ...`, but bear in mind using **global variable** *is not at all recommended and is a very bad practice.*

Comment: Please don't suggest to do a global assignment.